# My ListView does not show the images

Tags: android, listview

This is the Main_Activity

```
Integer[] imgid = {R.drawable.frame3,R.drawable.frame3,R.drawable.frame3,R.drawable.frame3,
            R.drawable.frame5,R.drawable.frame6,R.drawable.frame7,R.drawable.frame8,
            R.drawable.frame9,};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_image_activity);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("image");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        img_img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        img_img.setImageBitmap(bmp);


        Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this,imgid);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.e("Your in Main","Welcome_______");

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String pos=Integer.toString(position);
                Toast.makeText(EditImageActivity.this, "Your Position is"+pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the Adapter class___________

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final  Integer[] images;

    public Adapter(Activity context,  Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_image);
        this.context=context;
        this.images=imgid;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.e("Your in getView","Welcome");
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_image, null,true);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_img);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem ??

Comment: first of all, remove the comma from last element in array.. `imgid` . Second, is it showing any error or something?

Comment: getView method is not called in Adapter class

Comment: No,there is no any error.

Comment: is it the whole code of Adapter class ?

Comment: I removed comma but still it is not showing-

Comment: Yes it is whole code.

Comment: You need to override the `getCount()` method in your `Adapter` to return `images.length`.

Comment: and check your xmls also.

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I got result by Override getCount() method.

Answer (score 0):

update

```
View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_image, null,true);
```

with

```
View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_image, null);
```